# Run time error '13' type mismatch when hiding/unhiding rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have built a dynamic excel form, where all the relevant rows unhide only when you make a selection from a drop down list. Everything was working fine, until I have decided to add more rows and want them to be hidden within the section, until a specific selection is made. In other words, my sections unhide based on the top selection, but now there is a need to keep some rows hidden within those sections, until a drop down triggers them to unhide.

I have tried to break down the section unhiding in to pieces, like instead of unhiding whole 10 rows, I only unhide some first rows and then the rest ones, while keeping the middle ones hidden, until they are triggered by another selection.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row = 2 Then
       Select Case Target.Value
        Case "New deployment"
            [3:3].EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case Else
            [3:76].EntireRow.Hidden = True
            [B5:B11].ClearContents
            [B31:B38].ClearContents
            [B40:B46].ClearContents
            [B13:B23].Value = "Not included"
            [B48:B58].Value = "Not included"
            [B3:B3].Value = "Please select"
       End Select
    End If    
    If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row = 3 Then
            Select Case Target.Value
            Case "One device"
                [4:29].EntireRow.Hidden = False
                [8:9].EntireRow.Hidden = True
                [30:76].EntireRow.Hidden = True
                [B31:B38].ClearContents
                [B40:B46].ClearContents
                [B48:B58].Value = "Not included"
            Case "Two devices"
                [4:29].EntireRow.Hidden = True
                [30:64].EntireRow.Hidden = False
                [34:35].EntireRow.Hidden = True
                [43:44].EntireRow.Hidden = True
                [B5:B11].ClearContents
                [B13:B23].Value = "Not included"
            Case Else
                [4:76].EntireRow.Hidden = True
                [B5:B11].ClearContents
                [B31:B38].ClearContents
                [B40:B46].ClearContents
                [B13:B23].Value = "Not included"
                [B48:B58].Value = "Not included"
           End Select
        End If

        If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row = 2 Then
           Select Case Target.Value
            Case "Modification"
                [65:70].EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case Else
                [65:70].EntireRow.Hidden = True
           End Select
        End If

        If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row = 2 Then
           Select Case Target.Value
            Case "Disconnect"
                [71:76].EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case Else
                [71:76].EntireRow.Hidden = True
           End Select
        End If

        If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row = 13 Then
           Select Case Target.Value
            Case "Included"
                [9:9].EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case Else
                [9:9].EntireRow.Hidden = True
           End Select
        End If

        If Not Application.Intersect([B5:B5], Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
           [B6:B7].ClearContents
        End If

        If Not Application.Intersect([B31:B31], Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
           [B32:B33].ClearContents
        End If

        If Not Application.Intersect([B40:B40], Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
           [B41:B42].ClearContents
        End If

        If Not Application.Intersect([B6:B6], Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
           [B7:B7].ClearContents
        End If

        If Not Application.Intersect([B32:B32], Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
           [B33:B33].ClearContents
        End If

        If Not Application.Intersect([B41:B41], Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
           [B42:B42].ClearContents
        End If
    End Sub
```

The

> mismatch error '13'

began to appear as soon as I have added the following block:

```
If Target.Column = 2 And Target.Row = 13 Then
   Select Case Target.Value
    Case "Included"
        [9:9].EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Else
        [9:9].EntireRow.Hidden = True
   End Select
End If
```

Comment: On which line is the error?

Comment: You can't compare `Target.Value` to a string if `Target` is a multi-cell range. What is the address of `Target`?

Comment: Also - `Range(Target.Address)` is redundant. Just use `Target`.

Comment: My bad, the error shows up on the third line of the newly added block, which is this:
        Case "Included"

Comment: @BigBen sorry, I don't think I get your first comment. This is probably one of my first codes, I don't think I am comparing anything here, but instead I want to say that if there is a specific value within a specific cell, then unhide a specific row.

Comment: What is `Target.Address`? `Case "Included"` compares `Target.Value` to the string `"Included"`. But if `Target` actually is multiple cells, then this comparison will fail.

Comment: The address is a cell at B13 and yes, there are more cells, B13:B23 contains all values as "Not included" by default. I somehow have a feeling, that addressing a specific cell with Target.Column And Target.Row does not work as expected, but I don't know how to specify it otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: You are right. If your range is `B13:B23`, then its `.Row` is 13 and its `.Column` is 2. Are you concerned with the entire range `B13:B23`, or do you just want to work with `B13`?

Comment: You probably need to toggle `Application.EnableEvents` to `False` at the beginning and then to `True` at the end. `[B13:B23].Value = "Not included"` - any time you modify the sheet within the worksheet_change event, the event fires again. Is that what you want?

Comment: I only want to work with B13 and yes, every time my top level drop down is changed, I basically revert the selections made in the section to blanks or default values, such as "Not included".

Answer (score 0):

I have eventually managed to overcome the error by changing the mentioned block of the code to this:

```
    If Range("B13").Value = "Included" Then
    [9:9].EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
    [9:9].EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
```